# Compiling Errors in Netbeans with JFreeChart

Tags: java, swing, compiler-errors, classpath, jfreechart

When I run my project in Netbeans 8.1 nothing goes wrong. However, when I build it to a .jar file, there are 34 errors of missing packages and symbols all referring to JFreeChart. Couple of these errors:

```
C:NetBeansProjects\Program\src\org\jfree\chart\servlet\ChartDeleter.java:51: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingEvent;
C:NetBeansProjects\Program\src\org\jfree\chart\servlet\ChartDeleter.java:52: error: package javax.servlet.http does not exist
import javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionBindingListener;
C:\NetBeansProjects\Program\src\org\jfree\chart\servlet\ChartDeleter.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
public class ChartDeleter implements HttpSessionBindingListener, Serializable {
symbol: class HttpSessionBindingListener
C:\NetBeansProjects\Program\src\org\jfree\chart\servlet\ChartDeleter.java:98: error: cannot find symbol
public void valueBound(HttpSessionBindingEvent event) {
symbol:   class HttpSessionBindingEvent
location: class ChartDeleter

etc.....
```

My code is too long to post here (6000+ lines) and contains Java swing and some charts. Everything worked fine, but the charts made these errors appear. What's the reason for this?

Comment: check your class ChartDeleter, does it have the right import statements? are all the needed libraries in the dependencies of the project?

Comment: Looks like you miss the javax.servlet.jar and other rquired dependencies in your classpath

Answer (score 1):

"javax.servlet.http does not exist", add servletapi.jar to your classpath